# Zero vs. One-based counting in DataFrame.shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing an Excel sheet into a Python DataFrame which has first a row of text labels (1x11) and data (1733x1), which gives the sheet the size (1734*11).

```
filename = "data/raw_data.xlsx"
df = pandas.read_excel(filename, sheetname=0)
print(df.shape) # show number of rows and columns of DataFrame
```

Which returns: (1733, 11)

```
print(df.loc[0]) # show labels and first row of data
```

Which returns a list of the 11 labels and the first row value.

I understand that Python uses zero-based counting, so the 1733 means there are 1734 rows. But why then does it return 11 for the number of columns?

There are some missing values near the end of the DataFrame and one of the series starts with a NaNs, maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: `df.shape` returns the number of rows and the number of columns. Your data frame has 1733 rows and 11 columns. The column headers do not count as a row, and the index column does not count as a column.

Comment: Zero-based counting implies that the first row has index 0, so the 10th row has index 9. However, It does not affect how the *number* of rows or columns is calculated, only the *index*.

Comment: I have no issue with the rows, but I don't understand why Python says there are 11 columns. Starting to count from 0 (as Python does), there are 0, 1, ... 10 (so in Python language "ten") columns.

Comment: `there are 0, 1, ... 10 (so in Python language "ten") columns` what do you mean???? 0...10 is 11 columns not 10

Comment: @EdChum: yes. So I would expect print(df.shape) to return (1733, 10), not (1733, 11).

Comment: You seem oddly confused between indexing and counting, the shape is not 0 based, that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: The 1733 value does not include the header row

Comment: Ok, so I was not aware of the difference between indexing and counting in Python: `df.shape` returns the 1 based size of the DataFrame. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I think you may be confused because ```df.shape``` does not count the index as a column or the column index as a row. So if you read in a csv or excel which had 1734 rows but you set the column index then the df will only count 1733 rows. There's no such thing as 'one-based size'.

Answer (score 0):

There are 1733 rows and 11 columns in your dataset, numbered from 0 to 1732 and 0 to 10 respectively